# How to get Copyright footer to stay at the bottom even on smaller pages

Tags: html, css, footer, copyright-display

//CSS

```
footer {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
   width: 100%;
  }
p.copyright {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
   line-height: 10px;
   text-align: center;
    bottom:0;
}
```

//HTML

```
<footer>
  <p class="copyright">&copy Copyright 2022</p>
</footer>
```

My issue is the copyright logo is making my single page into more length, i presume due to the height of the footer - however whenever i reduce this its throwing the copyright into the middle of the page with a section blank underneath. How do i get my copyright to stay on the bottom middle no matter the page size?

Comment: Did you try setting absolute position? The problem with the footer is that (I believe) it takes the page size, whatever it is and hence if the page is, say, half screen, the footer will show just below the middle of the screen.

Comment: Tried this, on single pages it just shifts the copyright to just below the text or over it if the page is more than single length

Answer (score 0):

remove the position relative and absolute

```css
footer {
    height: 300px;
   width: 100%;
  }
p.copyright {
    width: 100%;
   line-height: 10px;
   text-align: center;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: When i remove the positions, the copyright just goes to the top of the footer with a gap between the footer and copyright

Answer (score 0):

Display flex to center, remove height add another div which will position paragraph on bottom

CSS:

```
    footer {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-top: auto;
    }
    p.copyright {
      margin: 10px;
    }
    body{
      min-height: 100vh; 
      display: flex; 
      flex-direction: column;
      margin: 0;
    }
```

As for html side

```
  <footer>
    <p class="copyright">&copy Copyright 2022</p>
  </footer>
```

Updated

Comment: Thanks for this, However, was not a success - Worked on most pages except a contacts form page - was displaying the copyright within the form

Comment: I have updated my answer, try doing something like this, I'm unsure if this will mess with other stuff on your pages tho.

Comment: Played around with this and switched a few things round, fixed the copyright showing over the form but now it displays half way up my smaller pages with little content - I will get there in the end - appreciate your help